# What does the number after the arguments mean in these commands?

Tags: ping, linux, testing

I think this is a very basic question but I could figure out a way to phrase question to find answers on google. I just started studying network management for a module of my degree a few days ago and the slides provided for the lesson are vague and doesn't explain some things.

```
You can test your network by these commands as well.

ping –i 5 127.0.0.1 (Time Interval e.g 0.1 sec)
ping –c 5 –q 127.0.0.1 (Count & Summary)
ping –s 100 127.0.0.1 (Size)
ping –w 5 destination (Timeout)
```

This is the exact description in one slide and there's nothing else, no explanations. Could someone explain what those 5, 100 magic numbers are?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find all the ping options by searching for *man ping* or *ping options*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those numbers are required parameters for the preceding option that is used: `-c 5` sends five echo requests, `-s 100` uses a payload/test data size of 100 bytes, and so on.